# How do I get a .wav or a .mid file to play outside of netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, wav, midi

I have created a simply login screen for a test game and it plays a .mid music tune. The .wav sounds are played when you hover over a button. When I Build+Compile the program, the both sounds play inside netbeans. When i run the .jar file outside of netbeans, it does not work. Any suggestions...

P.S.  The sounds are in a folder, inside the src folder, called resources. For .mid music, I use the sequence, and for .wav I use AudioInputStream and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that you are attempting to access application resources as though they were a `File`.  An application resource would usually be inside a Jar file, and must be accessed by `URL`.  To form the URL, use something like:

```
URL urlToMid = this.getClass().getResource("the.mid");
```

If that is not the case, then the next most likely problem is that the resource is not being included in the Jar.

Answer (score 0):

Without a code example, it's hard to help you out. Do you get an exception?

My guess is that your application cannot find the music files when running outside of NetBeans. Your home directory must be set to some value while running from NetBeans (probably pointing to your src/resource folder), but you specify a different home location (or none at all) when running outside NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

If the files **are** included in the generated .jar file, another possible problem is case-sensitivity. If the file is load from the regular filesystem (e.g. from within NetBeans), it depends on your operating system's filesystem if the filename is case-sensitive or not. On Windows it is not.

Once the file is loaded through a classloader (e.g. using getResource()), the filename is case sensitive and `Alert.wav` is a different file than `alert.wav`.

Make sure the filename in the source code is *exactly* the same way as it appears in the filesystem.